# Why is this HTML/JavaScript slideshow not changing through all of its images?

Tags: javascript, html, key, slideshow

I'm writing a small gallery/slideshow page that should change through its images using the left or right arrow keys. Currently, the code works somewhat, but does not change through all of its images. Why is this? How can it be fixed?

**Images for sample test :**

```
[
    'http://i.imgur.com/co6MlSo.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/gCxcOKi.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/lsu7ZSw.jpg',
    'http://i.imgur.com/pwysNhX.jpg'
];
```

**Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>gallery</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body{
        background: #333333;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial Black;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    img{
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img
            alt="slideshow"
            src="co6MlSo.jpg"
            id="imgClickAndChange"
            onclick="changeImage()"
        />
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var images = [
        "co6MlSo.jpg",
        "gCxcOKi.jpg",
        "lsu7ZSw.jpg",
        "pwysNhX.jpg"
    ];

    function changeImage(dir){
        var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
        img.src = images[images.indexOf(img.src) + (dir || 1)] || images[dir ? images.length - 1 : 0];
    }

    document.onkeydown = function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == '37'){
            changeImage(-1) // left to display previous image
        }else if (e.keyCode == '39'){
            // right to display next image
            changeImage()
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would use jQuery on click instead of inline onclick. When I fiddle I got error that checkImage is not defined due to parameter-less call. If you use jQuery you can use conditional logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add conditions like :

```
if(dir=='next'){
    index++;
}else{
    index--;
}

if(index>images_length){
    index=0;
}else if(index<0){
    index=images_length;
}

img.src = images[index];
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var images = ["http://i.imgur.com/co6MlSo.jpg","http://i.imgur.com/gCxcOKi.jpg","http://i.imgur.com/lsu7ZSw.jpg","http://i.imgur.com/pwysNhX.jpg"];
var index = 0;
var images_length = images.length-1;

function changeImage(dir){
  var img = document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");

  if(dir=='next'){
    index++;
  }else{
    index--;
  }

  if(index>images_length){
    index=0;
  }else if(index<0){
    index=images_length;
  }

  img.src = images[index];
}

document.onkeydown = function(e){
  e = e || window.event;

  if (e.keyCode == '37'){
    changeImage('prev'); 
  }else if (e.keyCode == '39'){
    changeImage('next');
  }
}
```

```css
html, body{
  background: #333333;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
}
img{
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="slideshow">
    <img
         alt="slideshow"
         src="http://i.imgur.com/co6MlSo.jpg"
         id="imgClickAndChange"
         onclick="changeImage()"
         />
  </div>
</div>
```